# How to scroll to selected item in listBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am adding a Customer using stored procedures.
I somehow managed to select newly added customer after insertion, but I cannot focus on the record in listbox..

I tried everything, like :

```
lbxCustomers.ScrollIntoView(this.lbxCustomers.SelectedIndex);
```

and many modifications using Items and stuff, but nothing is working.
It's still not scrolling the view to selected item..
Any ideas?

It's WPF.

My init looks like this :

```
        private void init()
    {

        SqlConnection connection = null;
        SqlDataReader reader = null;

        try
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection(this.strConnection);
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName FROM Customers", connection);

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            ListItem listItem;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                listItem = new ListItem(reader.GetValue(0).ToString(), reader.GetValue(1).ToString(), reader.GetValue(2).ToString());
                this.lbxCustomers.Items.Add(listItem);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
            reader.Close();
        }

    }
```

init2 is the same except the line :

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName FROM Customers WHERE CompanyName = '" + correctID + "'", connection);
```

It reffers to ListItem which looks like this :

```
    class ListItem
{
    private string customerID, companyName, contactName;
    public ListItem(string customerID, string companyName, string contactName)
    {
        this.customerID = customerID.Replace("'", "''");
        this.companyName = companyName.Replace("'", "''");
        this.contactName = contactName.Replace("'", "''");
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.companyName + " (" + this.contactName + ")";
    }

    public string CustomerID
    {
        get { return this.customerID; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Show us the code where you adding it to the listbox

Comment: Have a read through this old blog post of mine. It talks about focusing a ListBoxItem but that involves scrolling it into view. The trick is to do it after the item containers have been generated and using the Dispatcher. http://matthamilton.net/focus-a-virtualized-listboxitem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
        ListItem listItem = null;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            listItem = new ListItem(reader.GetValue(0).ToString(), reader.GetValue(1).ToString(), reader.GetValue(2).ToString());
            this.lbxCustomers.Items.Add(listItem);,
            lbxCustomers.SelectedItem = listItem;
        }
```

Comment: I tried but last line throws an error :
No overload for method 'Select' takes '0' arguments

Comment: @user1938719 well, i've tried it in windows forms. Does this work without Select() ?

Comment: No. I get :
Use of unassigned local variable 'listItem'

Comment: @user1938719 set ListItem listItem = null;

Comment: Ok, but it always sets it to last item.
I need it to set (and focus in the lisy) to my newly added item after I perform Insert Customer. There is my problem.. :/

Comment: Well it still targets last one (plus works soooo slow on bigger lists :)) But I managed to grab ID of newly added item by : looping in NewCustomer methos :
for(...){
lbxCustomers.Items[i].ToString().Contains(IDIlookFor)
}

Now I need just focused on item with gived ID.
Thanks for help!